# Efficient way of re-numbering elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I am reasonably new to python and am trying to implement a genetic algorithm, but need some assistance with the code for one of the operations.

I have formulated the problem this way:

- each individual `I` is represented by a string of `M` integers
- each element `e` in `I` takes a value from 0 to `N`
- every number from 0 - `N` must appear in `I` at least once
- the value of `e` is not important, so long as each uniquely valued element takes the same unique value (think of them as class labels)
- `e` is less than or equal to `N`
- `N` can be different for each `I`

after applying the crossover operation i can potentially generate children which violate one or more of these constraints, so i need to find a way to re-number the elements so that they retain their properties, but fit with the constraints.

for example:

```
parent_1 (N=5): [1 3 5 4 2 1|0 0 5 2]
parent_2 (N=3): [2 0 1 3 0 1|0 2 1 3]

*** crossover applied at "|" ***

child_1: [1 3 5 4 2 1 0 2 1 3]
child_2: [2 0 1 3 0 1 0 0 5 2]
```

`child_1` obviously still satisfies all of the constraints, as N = 5 and all values 0-5 appear at least once in the array.

The problem lies with child 2 - if we use the `max(child_2)` way of calculating N we get a value of 5, but if we count the number of unique values then N = 4, which is what the value for N should be. What I am asking (in a very long winded way, granted) is what is a good, pythonic way of doing this:

```
child_2: [2 0 1 3 0 1 0 0 5 2]
*** some python magic ***
child_2':  [2 0 1 3 0 1 0 0 4 2]
*or*
child_2'': [0 1 2 3 1 2 1 1 4 0]
```

`child_2''` is there to illustrate that the values themselves dont matter, so long as each element of a unique value maps to the same value, the constraints are satisfied.

here is what i have tried so far:

```
value_map = []
for el in child:
    if el not in value_map:
        value_map.append(el)

for ii in range(0,len(child)):
    child[ii] = value_map.index(child[ii])
```

this approach works and returns a result similar to `child_2''`, but i can't imagine that it is very efficient in the way it iterates over the string twice, so i was wondering if anyone has any suggestions of how to make it better.

thanks, and sorry for such a long post for such a simple question!

Comment: How did you get from `child_2` to `child_2''`?

Comment: if you think of the values as class labels it makes more sense, so starting at the first element in child_2 and taking 0 as the first label, each time a 2 appears in child_2, it is replaced by a 0.. then each time a 0 appears, it is replaced by a 1 (the second class). does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, now that you explained it, it makes sense. Isn't this exactly what your sample code does (you wrote it is only "similar")?

Comment: yes it does return exactly the same, but i meant similar in the sense as it returns that "class" of strings, as opposed to the class that `child_2'` belongs to

Comment: If you fix up the constraint on the child _after_ crossing, you're conflating values from different parents. That is, you're forcing value `0` from parent 1 to mean the same thing as value `0` from parent 2 - is this correct behaviour for your problem?

Comment: this occurred to me as well, and im not entirely sure of the answer.. the problem is a graph colouring problem, and the idea is to colour a graph with no matching neighbours, with as few unique colours as possible, so the numbers dont really matter as they just represent classes of colours and an edge that goes (2)---(3) is just as valid a solution as (1)---(2) - so its not the numbers, but the relationships that matter.. but you are probably right - if i apply this method after crossing, i will lose a bunch of those relationships..

Comment: i agree that the problem itself needs a bit more thought, however the post was just about how to achieve something in python, so in that sense, it has been a success.. now to go back and think about my algorithm some more..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to iterates the list more than once, I don't think there's any way around this. After all, you first have to determine the number of different elements (first pass) before you can start changing elements (second pass). Note, however, that depending on the number of different elements you might have up to O(n^2) due to the repetitive calls to `index` and `not in`, which have O(n) on a list.

Alternatively, you could use a `dict` instead of a `list` for your `value_map`. A dictionary has much faster lookup than a list, so this way, the complexity should indeed be on the order of O(n). You can do this using (1) a dictionary comprehension to determine the mapping of old to new values, and (2) a list comprehension for creating the updated child.

```
value_map = {el: i for i, el in enumerate(set(child))}
child2 = [value_map[el] for el in child]
```

Or change the child in-place using a `for` loop.

```
for i, el in enumerate(child):
    child[i] = value_map[el]
```

Comment: I don't think this would work on some examples, for instance if you have two values that are bigger than the num_val with different offsets.

Comment: Nice edit, I think you can just delete the first suggestion. The second one is an elegant way of solving this problem seeing how the actual values don't matter as long as the "mapping" is the same.

Comment: thanks, now i just need to unpack what that all means, hehe.. is it creating a dictionary called value_map, consisting of el from set(child) mapping to an incrementing counter, and then replacing the values in child corresponding to that mapping?

Comment: how is `for` used in this case, if you wouldnt mind giving a brief explanation? as in `i for i`...

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, i have to read up on using comprehensions i think.. it has been something i have been avoiding since starting to use python for some reason..

Comment: I wrote a library for doing this with numpy arrays quickly https://github.com/seung-lab/fastremap/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single loop like this:

```
value_map = []
result = []
for el in child:
    if el not in value_map:
        value_map.append(el)
    result.append(value_map.index(el))
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it returns `[2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 2]`

Comment: I don't know how you executed the code, but it does exactly what the code piece by @guskenny83 does.

Comment: My bad, it does work! The problem though is that you go through `value_map` twice each iteration (one for `el not in value_map`, one for `value_map.index`) ; Both can be O(1) if you use a `dict` instead of a `list` (look at my answer or @tobias_k's)

Answer (score 1):

One solution I can think of is:

1. Determine the value of N and determine unused integers. (this forces you to iterate over the array once)
2. Go through the array and each time you meet a number superior to N, map it to an unused integer.

This forces you to go through the arrays twice, but it should be faster than your example (that forces you to go through the `value_map` at each element of the array at each iteration)

```
child = [2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 2]

used = set(child)
N = len(used) - 1
unused = set(xrange(N+1)) - used

value_map = dict()
for i, e in enumerate(child):
    if e <= N:
        continue
    if e not in value_map:
        value_map[e] = unused.pop()
    child[i] = value_map[e]
print child # [2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @Selçuk Cihan answer. It can also be done in place.

```
>>> child = [2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 2]
>>>
>>> value_map = []
>>> for i in range(len(child)):
...     el = child[i]
...     if el not in value_map:
...         value_map.append(el)
...     child[i] = value_map.index(el)
...
>>> child
[0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this works, although I didn't test it for more than the single case that is given in the question.

The only thing that bothers me is that `value_map` appears three times in the code...

```
def renumber(individual):
    """
    >>> renumber([2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 2])
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 0]
    """
    value_map = {}
    return [value_map.setdefault(e, len(value_map)) for e in individual]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast solution, which iterates the list only once.

```py
a = [2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 2]
b = [-1]*len(a)
j = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if b[a[i]] == -1:
        b[a[i]] = j
        a[i] = j
        j += 1
    else:
        a[i] = b[a[i]]

print(a) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 0]
```